# Problems with a bootstrap carousel slider when looking the website in a mobile device. Everything slides in the website.

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, carousel

I´m having a problem with the responsiveness with a bootstrap carousel, **everything slides** in (all the content in the website slides, **when opening the website in a mobile device**) and I just want to make the carousel behave as it is supose to (Only sliding the images in the carousel, the rest need to be static as it is).

The website is http://www.ficuniandes.com and **if you check it out in a mobile device** (mostly happens in IOS devices) **it will slide all the content in the website**, so the experience become very unpleasant for who is watching it.
In Android devices it just slides the menu when you have it open. (The menu slides with the carousel).

I've tried to figure it out but don't know whats happening. I've changed the carousel several times and the same is still happening.

Thanks.

Here is the code of the carousel.

```
<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="https://ingbiomedica.uniandes.edu.co/images/CampusSame.jpg" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1 style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">Bienvenido al Club de finanzas de la universidad de los Andes</h1>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary boton-inicio" id="open-popup" role="button">Suscribete al boletín</a></p>
          
          <!--<p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="open-popup" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="https://ingbiomedica.uniandes.edu.co/images/CampusSame.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1 style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">Con nosotros podrás aprender como se mueve el mundo financiero</h1>
          <!--<p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>-->
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary boton-inicio" href="#" role="button">Suscribete al boletín</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

**Thanks.**

Comment: Thanks to Rick I notice that when I paste the code here I missed a closing div tag. but I check it in my code and there are all the closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your [div class="carousel-inner"] element.

Comment: Thanks Rick, didnt notice it when I paste it in the publication. But I check it in my code and I have the closing tag. So I guess that is not the problem. But thanks.